# How to exit Python script in Command Prompt?

Tags: python, windows

On previous computers, when I would try to exit a Python script on the Windows command prompt, all you need to do is press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

But when I do that on my computer it tells me "KeyboardInterrupt":

```
C:\Windows\System32
>python
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> [I press ctrl+c]
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

So how do I fix this so I can exit the Python script?

Thanks.

**Edit**:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> works, but I need to enter it as code. Was hoping for a quick and easy way to just exit the script, but oh well.

Comment: ctrl+c stops any process currently running. Use `quit()` to exit the console.

Comment: press <CTR>+d to exit

Comment: Try typing in 'exit()' instead.

Comment: @elyashiv that doesn't work on Windows (at least not on my machine - Windows 10  with Python 3.6)

Comment: @UnholySheep Thats funny. works with nodejs on windows.

Comment: @elyashiv I know, also works with Ruby's **irb** - but for some reason Python doesn't accept it. It does work with Ctrl+Pause/Break though

Comment: @3novak, Python has a Ctrl+C handler that defaults to raising a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. That it's not working in Windows 8+ prior to 3.6 is due to a bug in Windows, as I've explained below. The control event that we never handle automatically is Ctrl+Break. That will immediately and ungraciously terminate the process. It's a crude way to exit a process in general, and should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It indeed depends on the OS, and probably on the version of Python you are using.

As you mentioned, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not work on your Windows 10 with Python 3.6, but it does work on my Windows 10 with Python 3.4. Therefore, you really need to try and see what works for you.

Try the following commands, and keep the one that works:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd>

In addition, the following should work with any terminal:

- `exit()` then <kbd>Return</kbd>
- `quit()` then <kbd>Return</kbd>

Trivia: if you type `quit` and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, the console tells you, at least for Python 3.4:

> Use quit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit

Comment: Ctrl+C only "works" (it's a bug) in Windows 8+ prior to Python 3.6 because the Windows [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467) implementation broke its API contract to set the last error to `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED` when reading from the console is interrupted by Ctrl+C. Without that, Python's REPL thinks the read successfully returned 0 bytes, i.e. end of file, and exits. 3.6 switched to calling `ReadConsoleW` to better support Unicode, and this function sets the proper error for a read interrupted by Ctrl+C.

Comment: `ReadFile` returns EOF if the buffer read from the console starts with Ctrl+Z, but it's a cooked read so you have to press enter to complete the read. [`ReadConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684958) doesn't implement this hack, so Python's REPL in 3.6 implements this on its own. But since it's using `ReadConsole`, I think it should also use the `pInputControl` parameter to support an immediate Ctrl+D, similar to a Unix terminal.

Comment: `exit` and `quit` are provided by the `site` module. They're not available if you run Python with the `-S` option that prevents importing `site`. They're a convenience for the REPL. A script should instead rely on `sys.exit([exit_code])` or `raise SystemExit([exit_code])`.

Comment: On Python-3.6.1 for Windows 7, **exit()** and **quit()** do not work and produce the error *NameError: name 'exit' is not defined*. Ctrl+Z and Enter still do work.

Answer (score 10):

For an embedded python (e.g. `python-3.6.8-embed-win32`) `quit()` command does not work

```
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 23 2018, 23:31:17) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> quit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'quit' is not defined
```

The only way that works is: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply type "quit()" and its done!
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will interrupt a running script; but you only want to quit the interpreter. So quit() function will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

ctrl+Z works still

```py
..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37>python
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>>
>>> (1+4)*2
10
>>> ^Z
```

Comment: Please add some context to the _code snippet_ for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

my case(Python 3.9.6 on win10):

1 running script from the console

server:
[image]
client:
[image]

2 stop script in Task Manager, select py.exe(not python.exe) and click the "end task" button.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To his problem: How to close a python server(.py) or client(.py) in the cmd window.

The answer is: cntrl + Pause or Break
(Usually somewere above the left/up/down/right keys)

If that is not on your keyboard, close the cmd window and restart the server.

Eryk Sun already mentioned it, but for some reason his post isnt directly visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use exit() or quit() if you're using Windows(I found crtl combinations absolutely didnt work and ctrl+c gave me keyboard interrupt error)

Comment: This is already mentioned in the accepted answer

Answer (score -2):

for windows 10 python 3.9 try to type exit()

Comment: `exit()` was already mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41524896/7851470).